# Delayed Jobs not executing Queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job

Rails app running on v5.2. using puma server and postgres DB. Delayed Jobs not running Jobs Queues. On DJ service starts got below error message and DJ terminates but rake jobs:work command is running jobs without any issues.

```
RAILS_ENV=development bin/delayed_job start
```

return error message as

```
E, [2018-06-23T15:43:34.630732 #4316] ERROR -- : 2018-06-23T15:43:34-0700: [Worker(delayed_job host:WA021Z7GTFM pid:4316)] Job UploadSpeechJob (id=2066014) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"asset_files"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

this issue persists on all environments. I had tried restarting DJ, with no luck. 
As a work around I'm using this command.

```
RAILS_ENV=development rake jobs:work
```

application migrated from 4.2 to 5.2 recently. Does Delayed Jobs supports rails v5.2. Could some one points me in right direction.

Comment: That query is just asking for types of the columns in the asset_files table.  you could try a `reindex table` `vacuum_full` or `cluster` on that table, but that will probably not help.   Are you able to make database backups?

Comment: loaded backup in local environment recently.

Comment: I'm sure, this is not problem with asset_files index. truncated table and reset the index with no luck.

Comment: have you solved this? I'm running into a similar issue, delayed job is not running at all for me, I have no idea how to debug either

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from rails 5.1.6 to rails 5.2.4.1, I was experiencing something similar.  In 5.1.6, it was sufficient to have

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

in my config/application.rb file, and not needing it in any of the environment-specific files.

On a lark, I put

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```

into my **config/environments/development.rb** file, and suddenly the job started firing.